# Elastic potential energy per unit volume,stress-strain and strain-stress curve

Tags: quantum-mechanics, material-science, elasticity, solid-mechanics, applied-physics

From what I understand, when we calculate elastic potential energy per unit volume of a material which extends linearly, we calculate the area under the graph of stress- strain OR strain- stress graph, they both will give the same value. Likewise, if I want to calculate the elastic potential energy of a linear extension, I could get the value from the area under the graph of force-extension/ extension- force graph. However, I am unable to understand why we can’t do the same for a non linear extension. For example in a non linear extension, the areas obtained from stress-strain and strain-stress curve are not the same. I only know that this has something to do with integration, but I still can’t seem to wrap my head around it. 
So to conclude, my question is
1) why we can’t obtain elastic potential energy per unit volume under a curve of a strain stress graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F=kx$, in which $k$ is a constant,
$$\int_{x=0}^X Fdx=\int_{x=0}^X kxdx=\left[\tfrac12\ kx^2\right]^X_0=\tfrac12F_XX$$
in which $F_X=kX$.
But
$$\int_{F=0}^{F_X} x dF=\int_{x=0}^X x d(kx)=\int_{x=0}^X k x dx=\tfrac12F_XX$$
This equality of the two integrals is wholly dependent on our initial assumption: $F=kx.$ The same argument applies for the stress vs. strain graph.

Less precisely, if the graph of $F$ against $x$ started as $F=kx$ but curved upwards for higher values of $x$, this would make the area between the graph and the x-axis (up to a given value, $X$) higher, but would make the area between the graph and the $F$ axis (up to $F_X$) lower!

Comment: Thank you. However, which area under the graph would be the correct representation of work done?

Comment: The area between the graph line and the $x$ axis. This follows from the definition of $work.$

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it.

Comment: @YSH, if this answer your question you should considering accepting it.